# How do I count objects by attribute value?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, count, grouping

Part 1. I have an object called Cards. It has Name, Suit and Value attributes (Jack, Diamonds, 2). I want to count if a player has four-of-a-kind (4 cards have the same Name attribute). How can this be accomplished? I'm looking for an efficient algorithm.

Part 2. I need an algorithm for finding 5 cards in a row of the same suit (i.e. 7, 8, 9, 10, jack of hearts). Many thanks in advance to all you smart folks out there!

To clarify, each player is dealt 8 cards total. Player (object) has an attribute called Hand which is a list of Cards [object].

Comment: For part 1: what data structure do you have for a player? That is, how do you represent the player's collection of cards? For part 2: finding 5 cards in a row from among what?

Comment: Do you mean finding out if the player's hand has 5 cards in a row?

Comment: thanks. each player is dealt 8 cards total. Player object has a Hand attribute which is a list of cards. Hope I answered your questions. I'll also update the question to be more clear.

Comment: precisely. sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: @pnduke do you have some code to post, or expect us to write everything for you?

Comment: For finding out if a player has 5 cards in a row you could assign each card value an int. Ace = 1, numbered cards = numbered value, jack = 11, queen = 12, king =13. You could then sort the cards to determine the lowest card value in the hand, then determine if a card of the next value is also in the hand, inside a loop which runs 5 times. If you get to a value which is not in the hand you break the loop, if you get to the end you have a run. Also since you have 8 cards you would have to repeat this this for the next 3 lowest numbers to ensure you don't have a run which starts higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 1 you can do this:

```
var has4ofaKind = cards.GroupBy(c => c.Name).Any(g => g.Count() >= 4);
```

For part 2, it would be a lot easier if you had a property, say `Value`, as integer instead of string. Then you could do this:

```
var firstSuit = cards.First.Suit();
var isFlush = cards.Skip(1).All(c => c.Suit == firstSuit);
var isStraight = !cards.OrderBy(c => c.Value)
                       .Select((c, i) => c.Value - i)
                       .Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
var isStraightFlush = isFlush && isStraight;
```

*Note* this assumes a hand is 5 cards. To find a straight / flush of 5 cards in a hand of 8, you'd have to use something like this:

```
var hasFlush = cards.cards.GroupBy(c => c.Suit).Any(g => g.Count() >= 5);
var hasStraight = !cards.OrderBy(c => c.Value)
                        .Select((c, i) => c.Value - i)
                        .GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Any(g => g.Count() >= 5);
```

To find a straight flush is slightly trickier:

```
var hasStraightFlush= !cards.OrderBy(c => c.Value)
                            .Select((c, i) => new { x = c.Value - i, c.Suit })
                            .GroupBy(x => x)
                            .Any(g => g.Count() >= 5);
```

Comment: Gotta love LINQ.  Nice answer